# Returning only subdocuments in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have the following documents in my MongoDB collection:

```
{
   "name": "name",
   "items": [
        {
            "raw": { ... }
            "processed": { ... }
        },
        {
            "raw": { ... }
            "processed": { ... }
        }
   ]
}
```

And I'm trying to aggregate / query the database such that I get these items:

```
[
 {"raw": { ... }},
 {"raw": { ... }}
]
```

I'm using the aggregation framework now, but I'm stuck at the part where I want to exclude fields of the outer document.

My current query is:

```
db.mycollections.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$items" },
    { $project: { "items.raw": 1 } }
])
```

And it returns:

```
[
 {"items: {"raw": { ... }}},
 {"items: {"raw": { ... }}}
]
```

Is there a way to only return the subdocuments from the query above?

Comment: change your project like `{ $project: { "raw": "$items.raw" } }`

Comment: Ah yes, that works! Want to make an official answer out of it :)? Is this in the docs somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write aggregation with `unwind` as :

```
db.mycollections.aggregate({"$unwind":"$items"})
```

then output looks like :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId(), "name" : "name", "items" : { "raw" : {... }, "processed" : { ... } } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId() , "name" : "name", "items" : { "raw" : { ...}, "processed" : { ...} } }
```

[$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) passes along the documents with only the specified fields to the next stage in the pipeline. The specified fields can be existing fields from the input documents or newly computed fields.

and you pass `$project` as your existing fields with  `items.raw`  so instead of passing this existing field to project use [expression](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#agg-quick-ref-field-paths) with new field name as `raw` and changed your aggregation as

```
db.mycollections.aggregate({"$unwind":"$items"},{"$project":{"raw":"$items.raw"}})
```

For more details check **[mongo aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)**